# What is this yellow and black insect and how to get rid of them?

Tags: identification, insects

This insect creates a very small beehive like home in a corner of our pergola. What are they are how can I get rid of them?

I tried spraying [Ortho Home Defense insect killer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C4TS86I) but they came back.

Or maybe it's safe and I don't need to worry?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a yellow jacket or wasp which is a member of the [Vespula](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Yellow_jacket) genus.

They build communal nests out of paper but can also build nests inside houses and other places we consider unsuitable.

They can sting and are aggressive when defending their nest.

It is much easier to remove a small nest than a large one so act quickly and carefully.

At night when cooler temperatures promote less activity try and spray an insecticide with residual activity such as one containing Permethrin into the nest.

Another option for the bold or lucky is to try and knock the nest down with a stick and put it in a sealed container for disposal.

We had a nest inside the siding of our house so a pest control company was the best solution for us.

Comment: I got brave and knocked off the nest with a stick. They came back next day again and starting building a new one. I sprayed the Insect Killer but they came back again. Will probably try an insecticide now.

Comment: @zengr Be careful.  Wasps are evil.  Bees will only sting in self-defense, but a wasp is aggressive and will attack you for no good reason.  If you try to get rid of them and they won't leave, call an exterminator.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - comment upvote for "wasps are evil."  True dat.